# Speed up code when change in layout

Tags: php

I have website on php which have customization facilities for user.
When user change any layout the page will refresh and take much time to load.
I want to speed up the change in page layout.
The containts of page will be same but font -size ,back ground can be change without much time spending.

Please help me.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I don't really have enough information about the system to answer this question.

If it's just a font size or background change, shouldn't this be handled using CSS and not actually change any content?

If no content changes, then the user shouldn't have to reload the page at all. Just apply the new style rules to the document without reloading, and then either set a cookie to save it, or use an AJAX command to let the server know of the change so it can be saved.

A few links that might be useful:

- [Manipulating CSS style sheets with Javascript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dynamic-style-css-javascript/)
- [Introduction to Javascript AJAX requests](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/ajax.html)

Hope your site works out!

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Thank you for you.
Your given links are very usefull.